# What should the ideal salt content of a brine shrimp grow-out tank be?

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater, growing, brineshrimp

I am raising brine shrimp in a grow out tank and I normally use 1.018 specific gravity of salt in the hatchery. I have read online that the the ideal specific gravity can range from 1.018 to 1.045.

What is the ideal specific gravity of salt for raising brine shrimp to adulthood?